# Images between slides aren't smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have sliders in my code and when I first click through the slides it isn't smooth but after going through it once it becomes smooth. I do have several sliders and they all act the same. I can't seem to find an answer.  Can someone look at my code and see what I am doing wrong or what I may not be doing? Thanks for any and all help!

```js
// -------------- Image Slider --------------

var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var slideId = ["slide1", "slide2", "slide3", "slide4", "slide5", "slide6", "slide7"]
showImg(1, 0);
showImg(1, 1);
showImg(1, 2);
showImg(1, 3);
showImg(1, 4);
showImg(1, 5);
showImg(1, 6);

function side_slide(n, no) {
  showImg(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showImg(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
```

```css
/* slider */

.portfolio__port-item .images {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio__port-item .images .sliderImg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sliders {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 2s, ease-in;
}

.left {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sliders span {
  line-height: 41px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 2s, ease-in;
}

.sliders span:hover {
  color: #84b4b1
}


/* end of slider */
```

```html
<!---------- College Admissiosn HQ Website Content ---------->
<div id="CollegeAdmissionsHQWebsite" class="portfolio__port">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="portfolio__port-container">
      <div class="portfolio__port-description">
        <h2>College Admissions HQ</h2>

        <p>Role: Web Designer | Created: 2014-2018</p>
        <p>Programs Used: <span class="vsc">VSC</span> <span class="ps">Ps</span> <span class="wp">WP</span></p>
        <p>URL: <a href="https://www.collegeadmissionshq.org" target="_blank">collegeadmissionshq.org</a></p>

        <p> Since being hired by the online company, College Admissions HQ, LLC, to design their website, the trajectory of the company changed several times, and each time I redesigned the website to fit the new company goals. </p>
        <p>The current version of the website was built using a WordPress theme with the addition of custom HTML and CSS to create exact design elements to the client's specifications. The custom code was created using SCSS and HTML and then added into WordPress.
          The website includes a blog page and a resources page, both of which I set up for AdSense to run ads on. </p>

      </div>
      <!-- / .portfolio__port-description -->
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/bifold-menu-inside.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <div class="images">
          <img class="slide1" src="../img/bg1.jpeg">
          <img class="slide1" src="../img/bg2.jpg">
          <img class="slide1" src="../img/bg3.jpeg">
          <img class="slide1" src="../img/bg4.jpeg">
          <img class="slide1" src="../img/bg5.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- / .images -->
        <div class="sliders left" onclick="side_slide(-1, 0)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .left -->
        <div class="sliders right" onclick="side_slide(1, 0)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .right -->
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <div class="images">
          <img class="slide2" src="../img/bg6.jpeg">
          <img class="slide2" src="../img/bg7.jpg">
          <img class="slide2" src="../img/bg8.jpeg">
          <img class="slide2" src="../img/bg9.jpeg">
          <img class="slide2" src="../img/bg10.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- / .images -->
        <div class="sliders left" onclick="side_slide(-1, 1)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .left -->
        <div class="sliders right" onclick="side_slide(1, 1)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .right -->
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <div class="images">
          <img class="slide3" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/2883479/cover.jpg">
          <img class="slide3" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4360101/liberosis_--_12.png">
          <img class="slide3" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/3981307/lorena2.png">
          <img class="slide3" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/2883479/cover.jpg">
          <img class="slide3" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/545884/screenshots/4154721/dive--001.png">
        </div>
        <!-- / .images -->
        <div class="sliders left" onclick="side_slide(-1, 2)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .left -->
        <div class="sliders right" onclick="side_slide(1, 2)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .right -->
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Postcards/GLY-Postcard.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Postcards/Thank-You-1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Posters/Women-&-One-Acts-Poster.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Posters/Mystery-At-Senior-Manor.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Posters/An-Enchanted-Bookshop-Christmas-Poster.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Posters/Talent-In-the-Time-Of-Covid-Poster.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <img src="../image/TAFE/Posters/Talent-In-the-Time-Of-Covid-Poster.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__port-item">
        <div class="images slider-7">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Cover.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread1.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread2.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread3.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread4.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread5.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread6.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread7.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread8.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Spread9.jpg">
          <img class="slide7" src="../image/TAFE/Brochures-Programs-Handouts/Woman-And-One-Acts/Woman-and-One-Acts-Back.jpg">
        </div>
        <!-- / .images -->
        <div class="sliders left" onclick="side_slide(-1, 6)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .left -->
        <div class="sliders right" onclick="side_slide(1, 6)">
          <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sliders .right -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- / .portfolio__port-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- / .row -->
</div>
<!-- / #CollegeAdmissionsHQWebsite -->
```

Comment: Could you look into getting your snippet running? And what do you mean with "smooth"? Try looking into adding and removing classes, and use `opacity` with `visibility` for showing and hiding your slides for it will add support for transitions.

Comment: What does the `slideIndex` array do and why does it have values of either `1` or the length of the amount of slides?

Comment: As it isn't 'smooth' the first time through it may be because not all the images are fully loaded the first time through. Try setting a window.onload function and see if that makes any sort of difference.

Comment: The cdn images are around 200kb each.  What is the size range of the locally hosted images?  A problem I often see with sliders is using large 5-20mb images rather than images that are optimized for load time. There's rarely any justification for using high resolution images in a slider.